# Is it possible to bring built-in lightning components into aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have a form that needs to let the user select 3 out of 5 products, something similar to Order > Add Product (Modal). I was wondering if there was a way to bring that piece into my component (markup) and add some sort of filter that only shows the products I want to show.

What I found so far:

```
<lightning:listView objectApiName="Products2" listName="productsView" showActionBar="true" enableInlineEdit="true" showRowLevelActions="true"/>
```

But Product2 is not supported for that component.

also these from browser inspector:

```
forceMultiAddUsingLVM
forceListViewManager
```

These are data-aura-class attributes when rendered.

I'm looking for directions here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any standard component or UI that you see **cannot** be used in any custom components (unless you find any documentation to do so). Those components are not exposed at the framework level for any interaction using any customization.

Such components are usually core of the product itself and not exposed for any extension. What is exposed to developers are the lightning framework components which can be utilized as per the requirements to build any customizations.

In your scenario, you will need to build custom lightning component which will take care of the use case here.