# lightning component - mock data import

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I see this line of code in the lightning component library.

```
<aura:import library="lightningcomponentdemo:mockdataFaker" property="mockdataLibrary"/>
```

1. How do I access this library component?
2. I tried search for aura:import in the developer guide and could not find it's usage?

Can you please help?

Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to bring built-in lightning components into aura component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230924/is-it-possible-to-bring-built-in-lightning-components-into-aura-component)

Comment: @JayantDas I don't think so, actually.

Comment: @sfdcfox is there an `aura:import` component? I couldn't find it in the [component developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components).

Comment: @SFG - where do you see this being referred?

Comment: @JayantDas It's in the Salesforce Lightning Component Library

Answer (score 3):

aura:import is referenced by aura:library, which is part of the underlying framework for ltng:require. It is not part of the standard Lightning components, and cannot be used by developers. If you're interested, you can read more about it in [aura:library](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/auradev/library/library.auradoc), but this only matters if you're using Aura directly, and not developing in Lightning. None of this is for importing *data*, it's for importing JavaScript files into components.

Comment: thank you. In the above code snippet, where I found that in the Salesforce Lightning Component Library,  how do I access that library and see the JS files in it.

Comment: @SFG again, aura:import/aura:library is not meant to be used in Lightning. There's nothing in there for you unless you're working in Aura directly.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have also seen in places in the Lightning Component Library, for example in the [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) - they use `<aura:import library="lightningcomponentdemo:mockdataFaker" property="mockdataLibrary"/>` and I also tried to use it and failed. if we can't use it - they should not use it as an example...

Comment: @ItaiShmida I agree, it's very frustrating as the examples are not usable

Comment: see forum discussion https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005m4vQAA