# Is it possible to extend a standard rich content component's design attributes from the Community Builder?

Tags: custom, admin, design-attributes

Just to set your expectations I'm fairly new to developing lightning components.

The reason why I'm asking is I want to add additional functionality like a CSS class selection for a list so that an admin can copy/paste content directly on the content editors input box and set a style variant for that instance.

I've already tried creating a custom component, added a design attribute for selecting CSS classes that updates the component's inline CSS class. I've tried using `lightning:inputRichText` hoping that the admin could update that and I'll just do some Javascript manipulation to hide the input and just have the formatted output displayed on preview but clicking the dropped custom component would just open the property popup box.

To better explain what's my desired output, I have an illustration below.

[image]

Comment: Based on your illustration, seems you want to add a custom button to add a CSS to the Rich Content Editor, if that's what you are looking for then it's not possible. You may like to look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230927/54851) for further details.

Comment: Yes a custom button (and a rich text/text area field too ). If only there's a way to extend an out of the box lightning component. Anyway, thanks for the answer.