# Lightning component in quick action

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

We want to run custom lightning component in the lightbox for quick action. Is there any way to display the same layout but for custom component?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is lightbox?

Comment: @JayantDas it's standard lightning quick action lightbox from the quick action button. The example is Convert lead button.

Comment: You may like to check [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230927/54851). You cannot open any standard component in any custom component. You will need to completely re-design it.

Comment: @JayantDas I don't want to run standard component in custom component. I want to check layout for custom component in quick action.

Comment: do you just wanna increase the width of quick action modal?

Comment: You can use slds, lightning:layout, etc. I don't think your question is clear.

Comment: @sfdcfox I want to build custom component and run it in lightbox (like convert example above). Also I want to use the same layout: header, component body and buttons in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read [Configure Components for Custom Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm) and its related documentation, but basically you will want to implement force:lightningQuickAction or force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader, and if you want object-specific actions, also include force:hasRecordId. Try this as an example:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">
  Hello World!
</aura:component>
```

Once you create the component, go in to Setup, create a new quick action (e.g. Setup > Object Manager > Account > Buttons, Links, and Actions) using the component, then you can add it to your page layout. Once you've got the basic understanding of how it works, you'll be able to develop actions that can be used globally, per-object, or both, and choose to customize the buttons, etc. Everything you need is in the documentation. If you have specific questions, please feel free to follow up with a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I understand the main flow. The question is: is it possible to use standard layout/tags to display the same layout as standard component has: header/body/footer. Or should I use custom CSS to build it?

Comment: You would use [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com) or standard components like lightning:layout/lightning:layoutItem/etc. There's not much need to use *custom* CSS in ordinary cases.